# What is the difference between あれ and あの？

Tags: word-choice

Both terms mean over there but I am wondering if there are specific preferences of use. Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44575/9749

Answer (score 3, accepted):

あれ！ (The interjection) means like huh?!  as in

あれー、鍵をかけたと思った　　(huh!? I thought I locked the door

あの is used as a stutter device in sentences like "um" in English.

Answer (score 4):

They mean essentially the same, but あの is always used with a noun, and あれwithout one. Examples:

1. **あれ**は時計です。（There is a watch there)
2. **この**時計はあそこです。(This watch is there)

As you can see, in the 1st sentence, the emphasis is on the watch's location (is it in the speaker's space, in the listener's space, or elsewhere), while the in the 2nd the focus is on the watch.